# What is the easiest way to replace a design inside an Intel Cyclone SoC?

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, linux, soc

I would like to integrate my VHDL submodule to the FPGA fabric of an Intel Cyclone SoC and make it communicating with an App on its Linux.

There is lot of documentation on the internet but I am not able to find something "understandable".

Is there a kind of easy working approach to replace a bitstream (with a new qsys inside) for a Cyclone SoC with Linux on it?

I am afraid to have to rebuild a Linux with my new QSYS inside for my need.

Comment: Since we have no way to determine what you may or may not consider "understandable", it's impossible to answer this question. But in general, yes, if you modify the hardware platform (Qsys), the (Linux) software needs to be re-built to match that platform.

Comment: This for example: https://github.com/zangman/de10-nano/wiki is a doc which I consider not "understandable" ... I am not able to find some intel or board company official documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your post I assume the following:
You have a Terasic DE10-Nano-SoC board that comes with a Linux and an example FPGA image implementing RTL. That RTL perhaps controls on-board LEDs and implements registers that are implemented in the address space of the ARM processor (part of the SoC), right?
What you are asking is *how to write my own RTL code and access it from the Linux?*
This is not an easy job. There are many examples available but don't expect any *easy read* that will get you to a result in a few hours.

Platform Designer helps you mapping your RTL registers to the CPU address space. Creating a new custom component under Qsys (now Platform Designer) and editing the HDL template may be your best starting point.
Searching for examples and documentation got much harder when Altera Cyclone got re-branded as Intel post acquisition. There are many broken links to the date. Intel forum seems to be worse than Altera used to be but still worth diving in.

If you want to venture to the Linux build there is a great resource at:

https://forum.digikey.com/t/debian-getting-started-with-the-de0-nano-soc-kit/12434

This unfortunately doesn't cover the interfaces you would be building through the Platform Designer.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link this is the cleanest starting point documentation I have now. My main concern was to make Linux booting with my bitstream including my Qsys. For the FPGA <-> HPS communication, it's less complex and risky for my skills. I hope so...

Comment: I understand your pain. I embarked on a Cyclone V SoC project a bit more than a year ago and was desperate for information. Now - countless nights and thousands of System Verilog code later - I have things mostly under control but there are many "TODOs" in my code and some areas (i.e. Linux Device Tree" may be hanging on a thin string. Translation: It works but I cannot explain why :-)

Comment: One of the best documents that I found was

Comment: One of the best documents that I found was
https://moodle.epfl.ch/pluginfile.php/1680499/mod_resource/content/10/SoC-FPGA%20Design%20Guide%20%5BDE1-SoC%20Edition%5D.pdf
This is part of the course developed at EPFL Lausanne
https://moodle.epfl.ch/course/view.php?id=391
A word of caution:
If you embark to build the BSP, BootLoader and kernel from scratch you may be better off using Quartus 18.1 and work in a Linux environment (I used VMW, or VirtualBox).

Comment: The chip itself is old enough - so no real benefit using newer Quartus. and Intel dropped ARM compiler from Quartus in later versions and you have to go through extra hurdles to get the environment set-up. Linux? Quartus itself is a Linux program and seems to be happier (in extreme cases) in the native environment. So for the fundamentals I am using the above and once done with that keep running Quartus 18.1 directly in Windows to develop the RTL.

Comment: Thanks, now I just have to get to work :)